# How can this else if statement be improved?

Tags: java, if-statement

I need to find out what is wrong with this code and how it can be improved. What if I were to get more values?

Would an `else if` chain be better or a switch statement?

```
string StatusMessage(int value)
{
  string message;

  if (value == 1)
  {
    message = "A";
  }

  else if (value == 2)
  {
    message = "A";
  }

  else if (value == 3)
  {
    message = "A";
  }

  else if (value == 10)
  {
    message = "B";
  }

  else if (value == 20)
  {
    message = "C";
  }

  else if (value == 100)
  {
    message = "D";
  }

     return message;
}
```

Comment: Use switch statement, by the way your code won't compile.

Comment: `String` is uppercase

Answer (score 1):

You can use `switch` statement as already suggested in comments.

Other approach would be to define `Map<Integer, String>`, and use it as registry for messages by `int` values as follows:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private Map<Integer, String> messageByValue = new HashMap<>();
    {
        messageByValue.put(1, "A");
        messageByValue.put(2, "A");
        messageByValue.put(3, "A");
        messageByValue.put(10, "B");
        messageByValue.put(20, "C");
        messageByValue.put(100, "D");
    }

    public String statusMessage(int value) {
        return messageByValue.getOrDefault(value, "default");
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the map solution.  Much easier for additional status codes, and more scalable and elegant than a switch or else-if solution.

Answer (score 1):

In case you wish the very straight forward "naive" `switch-case` solution, I would go with this one:

```
public class HelloWorld
{

    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println(StatusMessage(100));
    }

    public static String StatusMessage(int value)
    {
        String message;
        switch(value)
        {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3: message = "A";
                    break;

            case 10: message = "B";
                     break;

            case 20: message = "C";
                     break;

            case 100: message = "D";
                      break;

            default: message = "";
                     break;
        }

        return message;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the capitalization of `string` (vs. `String`), it really doesn't matter...

Both a switch statement and if/else block will evaluate the same way when you get under the hood. It's really a matter of personal preference.

If the code you want it to run is that simple, and similar between options; typically, I would use a switch statement, just because it will tend to be more compact and neater looking. But as I said, it doesn't really matter.

I'll note, your question is "homework-esq", which is something we try to avoid on Stack Overflow. I'd encourage try both methods and see how the compare in work if you have to add say 3 more values - again probably not much different.